# Acoustic Noise on SMPS

Tags: mosfet, switch-mode-power-supply, pwm, esp8266

I'm developing an RGB LED driver and noticed some acoustic noise from the power supply.

The power supply is a cheap brandless 12V 20A, output voltage ripple is under 800mV @4A @50% duty. I have no problems with voltage ripple at LDO output, so i'm assuming the LDO is dealing well with input voltage ripple.

My board uses a ESP8266 with N-Channel MOSFETs (PN [AP30H60K](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/MOSFETs_ALLPOWER-ShenZhen-Quan-Li-Semiconductor-AP30H60K_C2995340.html)), with no gate drivers. The turn-on/off time is controlled by simple 1kohm resistor, that ensured an acceptable Vds (<15Vpeak). PWM frequency is 1kHz, and this is the cause of power supply acoustic noise.

I want to know if this can damage the power supply over the time.

[image]

Comment: I guess it is impossible for anyone to say yes or no to the question if this can damage the power supply over time.

Answer (score 1):

You won't damage the power supply. What you're hearing is either the coils or capacitors (or both) responding to the sudden changes in current. This is common on cheap (and sometimes not so cheap) power supplies when you pulse loads.

If you offset the R, B, and G channels so they take turns switching rather than doing it at the same time you'll reduce noise significantly whenever anything but a pure color is shown. You can also increase the resistance on the gate to slow switching. Increasing the frequency above the peak of human auditory sensitivity may also help.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say that the supply will be damaged, but it certainly is not healthy for it.

If the 1KHz PWM current pulses are appearing in the power supply, then the power line filter at the board is insufficient or non-existant. The schematic diagram shows no attempt at decoupling.

In addition, any reverse current pulses that might exist cannot easily be absorbed by the power supply so must be absorbed by external capacitance.

1kHz requires significant capacitance to decouple the circuit from the power supply. Greater than 20KHz is better.

Something like this should work. I have not made any estimations of the capacitances. I leave that up to you.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsqsOf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>